# Multiple addresses on Metamask

Tags: metamask, addresses

First of congrats for the great work in the forum! I´ve tried to avoid posting but I can´t find the solution to my problem, this is causing me lots of stress and I really don´t know what else to do now.

Recently I opened and account at myetherwallet.com, then I printed the Wallet and the private key. After this I installed MetaMask as you suggested but when I logged in using it, my address suddenly changed, the little picture also changed. It won´t allow me to download the Wallet and private key for this address, Im quite confused.
Now when I log in using metamask in Myetherwallet it takes me to this new address which is not the original one...

PD. I managed to open the original address account through the Keystore/JSON file method, but when accessing through Metamask it takes me to this other address...

I must have done something wrong in the process but can´t recall exactly what it is.
Kind Regads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metamask can hold multiple accounts and is initialized with a new one. You will need to import the account you created on MyEtherWallet into Metamask via the Keystore/JSON file.

Here is a video showing you how to do it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=grsBwSDSeuQ.

Comment: You are very kind Daniel, thank you for taking the time.

Comment: Hi @Joewhite, happy to have you in the community :)! If this or any other answer in the future has solved your question, you can consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This will indicate to the wider community that you’ve found a solution and makes it easier for others who may be experiencing a similar issue to find it, but also gives both the answerer and yourself some reputation :). This, however, is by no means obligatory and only do so if an answer has truly helped you! Good luck!